# Is it possible to auto-update the name of variables in two different directories

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, webstorm

I use Webstorm to test Javascript code with the testing framework Mocha. I want to give my variables and functions names which facilitate an intuitive understanding of my code in the best possible way. As a consequence I often rename my variables and functions.

So if I in the same project have `file1.js` in a `lib` folder with the following content:

```
var foo = 'I am a variable';
```

and `test_of_file1.js` in a `test`folder with the following content:

```
var foo = 'I am a variable';
```

and I use Webstorm's refactoring tool in `file1.js` to rename `foo` to `boo` I would like this change to take effect in both files. I do not use JsDoc to document the code or Git to track any changes (unsure if that is relevant). I have tried using refactoring, but it only takes effect in `file1.js`.

How can I make it take effect in both files?

Comment: what does your code look like? Rename refactoring should normally update variables/functions names throughout the project

Comment: @lena: Thank you for your comment. I am unsure of what you mean by "... throughout the project ...". I have my code and testing code in two separate files. I know of refactoring. But when I for example "rename" a variable it only takes effect in the working tab - not any others tabs. Is there any way to instruct webstorm to refactor across all files of a project .... ?

Comment: normally you don't need doing anything special for this - refactoring updates all occurrences found in project files. If this doesn't work for you, this likely means that WebStorm failed to find all occurrences

Comment: Well any ideas why Webstorm fails to find all occurrences? - just to point me in a direction I can investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two concepts.

When you're renaming something (*such as a file called in many other modules*), Webstorm will refactor all files containing such references.

In your case, you're essentially "replacing" the name of the var. But the var foo in file 1 is NOT a reference to var foo in file 2. They'Re two completely different things.

Based on what you described above, you need to do a FIND & REPLACE operation on your project & test files.
But be careful, and make sure to review each find/replace operation.

The problem above is that you refactored (*or find/replaced*) only within the open file. That won't work. You'll need to **select your project folder in the Project tab** (*should contain your project files and test files*) and type: **CTRL + SHIFT + R** (*might be different on windows*) to do a project-wide Find/Replace.

Comment: @Sebastian Daniel: Thank you! The short-cut did not work out but using the following menu path: `Edit` --> `Find` --> `Replace in path ...` I got it to work. What a relief.